# whats wrong with this mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my sql query

```
"INSERT INTO `userdetails`(`ID`,'Gender','RS') VALUES ('09090','0','1')";
```

i have set ID to be `bigint`and 'Gender' and 'RS' to be booleans.

Comment: Column names use backtics not single quotes. Values use single or double quotes (or no quotes for numeric values)

Answer (score 1):

Use back tics for column and table names. Single quotes are for values.

```
INSERT INTO `userdetails`
(`ID`,`Gender`,`RS`) 
VALUES 
('09090','0','1');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you are inputing a value for the ID you are passing in a char instead of a bigint. Also, for the boolean values they shouldn't be in quotes the should be either true or false. The query should look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO userDetails(Id, Gender, RS) 
VALUES(09090, true, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"INSERT INTO `userdetails`(`ID`,'Gender`,`RS`) VALUES ('09090','0','1')";
```

You should use the backtick (``) character to enclose column names. String values use regular quotes ('')